# How to find the browser versions from command-line in Linux & Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line-interface

In ubuntu when I just open a terminal and say 
"firefox -v" or "konqurer -v"
it prints all the version information.

But, I am not able to find how to go about this for

1. Chromium on Linux & Windows (7) [Couldn't get to work with this [link](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc) and this [link](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)
2. Firefox on Windows (7)
3. IE on Windows (7)

Previously on [Windows xp](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) executing "someexe.exe /?" used to show help and command line options for that exe. But it doesn't seem to be working for Windows 7. I tried "Chrome.exe /?" and it just starts chrome.

I know how to get it in GUI, but I would like to script it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a old question but it might help someone. (Donnow about Windows haven't used it in a long time ;)

Chromium and Google Chrome for Linux both have a command line flag to output the version. You can find them like:

```
google-chrome --product-version
```

and

```
chromium-browser --product-version
```

Many other interesting command line flags here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Hope it helps. :-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the linux flavor, but if its an RPM-Based OS (RedHat & its darivities mainly)

```
  rpm -qa | grep browsername
```

usually does the trick.

Comment: Awesome! I was looking for the debian version of it.

#apt-cache policy packagename
or
#apt-cache madison packagename

Apt-cache doesn't require "sudo".

Comment: Thanks! Post here if you have an answer for doing the same from Windows CMD (command-line) utility.

Comment: So you can get the version of IE (tested in xp):
reg query "hklm\software\microsoft\internet explorer" | findstr /i version

Comment: so of google chrome (installed as a normal user):

C:\>reg query HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google\Update\Clients\{8A69D345-D564-463c-AFF1-A69D9E530F96} | findstr /i pv

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is interested in getting the version from Chromium source without building it, it's in this file:

```
src/chrome/VERSION
```

and from a compiled chrome, as others mentioned the following works (at least on Ubuntu which I tried)

```
./chrome --product-version
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a version command line switch for Chrome in Windows; in general the command line switches begin with -- rather than a single -, and a good list of known ones appears here: http://www.waltercedric.com/component/content/article/1713.html

Comment: Cool. Thanks! But there doesn't seem to be one to check the build version.

Answer (score 0):

[Per Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977535.aspx), there is no way to get the IE version from the command line on Windows.  The "-v" switch is UNIX-only.